# codeigniter like flashdata in core php

Tags: php, session

is there any way to create flash session data like in codeigniter,
i want to create it in core php.

I don't want to use GET method, passing variable with url makes problem in my application.
so, how can i do this?

Comment: `$_SESSION` http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Its pretty easy to create a flash message class with PHP sessions.

```
class FlashMessage {

    public static function render() {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['messages'])) {
            return null;
        }
        $messages = $_SESSION['messages'];
        unset($_SESSION['messages']);
        return implode('<br/>', $messages);
    }

    public static function add($message) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['messages'])) {
            $_SESSION['messages'] = array();
        }
        $_SESSION['messages'][] = $message;
    }

}
```

Make sure you are calling `session_start()` first. Then you can add messages using `FlashMessage::add('...');`

Then if you redirect, you can render the messages next time you render a page `echo FlashMessage::render()`. Which will also clear the messages.

See http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: good code..flash message level also include this logic(like error,warning,notice etc) for improving