# PHP How to pass error marker after refreshing unsuccessful login

Tags: php

I have a login page and I want to achieve this effect:
If user fails to login, display error message. After user presses refresh button, the error message should not be visible anymore.

I dont want to pass $_GET variable, for example index?page=login$failure. I want to do this in invisible in url way.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit_form_register'])) {
  ...
    if($login === false) {
      $user->go_to('index.php?page=login'); //Redirects back, cleaning the $_POST data.
    }
  ..
  }
?>
```

Now how do I say for my form, that something before redirect went bad without addint it with $_GET?

Update. So using sessions, can I do like this?

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit_form_register'])) {
  ...
    if($login === false) {
      $_SESSION['is_form_error'] = true;
      $user->go_to('index.php?page=login'); //Redirects back, cleaning the $_POST data.
    }
  ..
  }
?>
```

And for HTML output:

```
  <?php if(isset($_SESSION['is_form_error']) and ($_SESSION['is_form_error'] === true)) { ?>
  <div>Your email or credential is invalid.</div>  
  <?php } unset($_SESSION['is_form_error']); ?>
```

But this one doesnt work for me. I bet its because something wrong with unset. Any tips?

SOLVED: Didn't have exit; after header(); in $user->go_to($url);

Comment: You could use a server-side [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) variable to store/clear an error message.

Comment: I am aware of this solution, forgot to mention it. Any other ways? Curious.

Comment: See related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153140/codeigniter-like-flashdata-in-core-php

Comment: Write the error to a database with a session ID.

Comment: $user->go_to('index.php?page=login&urlencode(status=unsuccess)'

Comment: Somewhere you have to set something before redirecting if you don't want to pass anything via url. So it can be as said before a SESSION variable, or a Global, or a DB insert, or a fileon the server. The best  shot is using sessions. If it fails, write $_SESSION['login_failed'] = true. Before sending the new form, after redirect, if $_SESION['login_failed'] === true, unset it, and display error. That way, any F5 won't display the message anymore. And i will add that using DB or file is a bad idea imo, trafficwise

Comment: I posted my attempt, which doesnt work. Tips?

Comment: Go read the answer that @SamDufel linked, especially the part about `session_start()`

Comment: My session is started in other file. So it's not the problem. It displays the message if I don't unset the session variable, but then I unset it, it doesnt display it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Session for show and hide errors
When user enter wrong user/pass you set error session and use it in view and then delete session(after showed)

```
`//Set Session
if (!$success) {
    $_SESSION['login_error'] = 1;
}
//show
if (isset($_SESSION['login_error'])) {
    echo "Invalid Username/Password";
    unset($_SESSION['login_error']);
}`
```

Don't forget to start code with session_start();

Comment: Well, we already discussed with all in comments, but as you are first person who posted as an answer, I'll accept your answer. My come was completely identical, the problem it didnt work is that in my function $user->go_to after header(); i forgot to write exit;